# How to get a datepicker like in the official Contacts app?

Tags: android, datepicker, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

The official Android Contacts app from Google has a really nice date picker. Is that somehow available to be used for my own applications? Otherwise, how could I build such a Datepicker in Compose? I really like how fast one can select a date compared to e.g. Material 3 Datepicker.

[image]

Comment: use a dialog and 3 laxy columns that scroll vertically inside a row

Comment: Have a look at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68187868/android-jetpack-compose-numberpicker-widget-equivalent).